# Vary parameter through time in ODE

Tags: r, ode, desolve

I am using the `deSolve` package to solve a differential equation describing predator-prey dynamics. As an example, below is a simple L-V predator-prey model. I would like some of the parameters in the model to vary through time. I can vary state variable (e.g. prey density) no problem using the `event` argument in the `ode` function.

But I cannot use the  `event` argument to alter parameters.

Here is the simple L-V model with no events added (works fine)

```
# Lotka-Volterra Predator-Prey model from ?deSolve::ode

# define model
LVmod <- function(Time, State, Pars) {
  with(as.list(c(State, Pars)), {
    Ingestion    <- rIng  * Prey * Predator
    GrowthPrey   <- rGrow * Prey * (1 - Prey/K)
    MortPredator <- rMort * Predator
    
    dPrey        <- GrowthPrey - Ingestion
    dPredator    <- Ingestion * assEff - MortPredator
    
    return(list(c(dPrey, dPredator)))
  })
}

# parameters
pars  <- c(rIng   = 0.2,    # rate of ingestion
           rGrow  = 1.0,    # growth rate of prey
           rMort  = 0.2 ,   # mortality rate of predator
           assEff = 0.5,    # assimilation efficiency
           K      = 10)     # carrying capacity


# initial densities (state variables)
yini  <- c(Prey = 1, Predator = 2)
# time steps
times <- seq(0, 200, by = 1)

# run model
out   <- ode(yini, times, LVmod, pars)

## plot
plot(out)
```

Here is the L-V model with state variable `Prey` multiplied by some `rnorm()`every 5 timesteps (works fine).

```
# add prey every 5 timesteps using events
add_prey <- function(t, var, parms){
  with(as.list(var),{
    Prey <- Prey * rnorm(1, 1, 0.05)
    return(c(Prey, Predator))
  })
}

# run ode - works fine
out <- ode(y = yini,
           times = times,
           func = LVmod,
           parms = pars,
           method = "ode45",
           events = list(func = add_prey, time = seq(0, 200, by = 5)))

plot(out)
```

Here is my attempt to increase K every 5 timesteps (does not work)

```
# vary K through time
add_k <- function(t, var, parms){
  with(as.list(var),{
    K <- K + 2
    return(c(Prey, Predator))
  })
}

# run ode
out <- ode(y = yini,
           times = times,
           func = LVmod,
           parms = pars,
           method = "ode45",
           events = list(func = add_k, time = seq(0, 200, by = 5)))
```

Which produces this error:

```
Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) : 
object 'K' not found
```

Based on the error K is not being passed to `add_k`, in `add_k` the line `with(as.list(var)` is obviously only accessing the variables `Prey` and `Predator`. In the `ode` and `event` helpfiles I can only find information regarding altering state variables (`Prey` and `Predator` in this case), and no information about altering other parameters. I am new to ODEs, so maybe I am missing something obvious. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: I guess you could define `K <- function(Time) 10 + 2 * floor(Time / 5)`, or similar, and evaluate `1 - Prey / K(Time)` inside of `LVmod`?

Comment: I have not read the full post yet, but agree with @Mikael Jagan. The following [short tutorial](https://tpetzoldt.github.io/deSolve-forcing/deSolve-forcing.html) may help you. And, there were already some other potentially related posts on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events are used to modify **state variables**. This means that at each event time, the ode solver is stopped, then states are modified and then the solver is restarted. In case of time-dependent **parameters*, this can be done much easier without events. We call this a "forcing function" (or forcing data).

A modified version of the original code is shown below. Here a few explanations:

- `approxfun` is a function that returns a function. We name it `K_t` that interpolates between the *data timesteps* `t` and the parameter values `K`. The argument `rule = 2` is important. It describes how interpolation is to take place outside the range of `t`, where `2`means that the closest value is returned, because some solvers overshoot the end of the simulation and then interpolate back. The `method` can be `constant` or `linear`, whatever is more appropriate.
- The interpolation function of the variable model parameter `K_t` can be added to the function as an optional argument at the end. It is also possible to define it globally or to include it in `parms`if it is defined as a list, not a vector.
- The `LVmod` function checks if this additional parameter exists and if yes overwrites the default of `K`.
- At the end of the `LVmod`function we return the actual value of `K` as an optional (auxiliary) variable, so that it is included in the model output.

```r
library(deSolve)

LVmod <- function(Time, State, Pars, K_t) {
  with(as.list(c(State, Pars)), {
    if (!is.null(K_t)) K <- K_t(Time)
    Ingestion    <- rIng  * Prey * Predator
    GrowthPrey   <- rGrow * Prey * (1 - Prey/K)
    MortPredator <- rMort * Predator
    
    dPrey        <- GrowthPrey - Ingestion
    dPredator    <- Ingestion * assEff - MortPredator
    
    list(c(dPrey, dPredator), K = K)
  })
}

pars  <- c(rIng   = 0.2,    # rate of ingestion
           rGrow  = 1.0,    # growth rate of prey
           rMort  = 0.2 ,   # mortality rate of predator
           assEff = 0.5,    # assimilation efficiency
           K      = 10)     # carrying capacity
yini  <- c(Prey = 1, Predator = 2)
times <- seq(0, 200, by = 1)

# run model with constant parameter K
out <- ode(yini, times, LVmod, pars, K_t=NULL)

## make K a function of t with given time steps
t   <- seq(0, 200, by = 5)
K   <- cumsum(c(10, rep(2, length(t) - 1)))
K_t <- approxfun(t, K, method = "constant", rule = 2)

out2 <- ode(yini, times, LVmod, pars, K_t=K_t)

plot(out, out2, mfrow=c(1, 3))
```

[image: time variable parameter]